# Bootsrap v4-alpha not working Collapse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with ASP.NET MVC. Here my accordion not start to collapse.

I've tried to add this javascript code:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#accordion').collapse({
            toggle: false
        })
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working. What could be the problem?

```
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        @foreach (var HB in pages)
        {
            <h2>@HB.Title</h2>

            foreach (var item in HB.Pages)
            {
                string cname = "collapse" + item.ID;
                string hname = "heading" + item.ID;

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="@hname">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@cname" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="@cname">
                                @item.Title
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="@cname" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="@hname">
                        @item.Description
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to explain your scenario in easiest way, so anyone can get it clearly. first things is what you are using and and what you have tried and then your sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me.

I think you are not including jquery before including bootstrap.  Reference this before bootstraps js file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is my codepen with your code working:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/GjQZoZ